# check if a string has any other character than '*'

Tags: python, string, function

I'd like to check whether a certain string contains any character other than `'*'`. for example:

```
str1 = "aaa*bbb" will return false

str2= "***" will return true
```

how can I do that?

[this is what I tried and it didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Fzt.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `all()` to perform the check:

```py
def check(s, char="*"):
    return all(ch == char for ch in s)


print(check("aaa*bbb"))
print(check("***"))
```

Prints:

```
False
True
```